# Is it compulsory to upgrade my app's Node.js version from v0.10 to v4 or v6?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My app is depends on Node.js, Swagger, Express and MongoDB.
I am using a very old version of Node.js v0.10.x.
I am unsure if my app will be used any longer after another 1.5years.
This seems like a long time when I consider how far behind I am the version.
However, upgrading the version will take a while and I am stuck for time.
In order to upgrade, I will have to look into all the changes between my version and the new one, then I will have to look into all the app dependencies and figure out if they will still work or if I need to upgrade them too and also update syntax based on findings.
So, I have been trying to figure out the implications of NOT upgrading.  However, I am struggling to come up with any answers.
I know my version is no longer supported, but how does that affect me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade asap. From the node LTS (long term support) working group [README](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS) `0.10.x` and `0.12.x` are no longer supported as of `January 2017`. So upgrading is the proper security minded move.

What you should do is use [n](https://github.com/tj/n) or [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to easily switch versions and test `4.7` `6.9` — The odd versions are beta, and while `node 8` won't be out until spring 2017—it's more likely than 4 or 6 to break your code.

Remember each time you switch versions to run `npm rebuild` in the project's root per the [npm api docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/rebuild).

I recently helped move most of the code rendering the WSJ's article pages from a node `0.10.x` codebase to `6.9-LTS`, but due to performance reasons had to settle for `4.7`.

There's a good chance things might just mostly work outside of some warnings in `4.x`—so it's definitely worth testing.

Answer (score 0):

Other developers can stop building packages for the older version. Then you would keep on saying things like: Oh that is available for a higher version, let me reinvent the wheel.